# Recommended Azure SQL Server Database Configuration

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I have a web application that have 500 users. I want to migrate to Azure.
I need to know what options to choose in configuring the sql server database such as compute + storage, sql elastic pool, redundancy and pricing. What is the minimum setup based on the current number of users.

Comment: What is your existing database configured with?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you go with Azure PaaS as that could be the best option for you. Below are the steps to deploy SQL database

1. Following this  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/deploy-azure-sql-database/6-exercise-deploy-azure-sql-database)  will show to how to deploy an SQL database
2. The need to enable all azure services to access new SQL server
3. Now we need to register Azure SQL DB instance in Azure Data Studio
4. And we can also query SQL database with SQL notebook.